# Compare two comma separated string and find the missing values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Which is the best way I can compare two C# string variables containing comma separated values and find the difference?

The scenario is like.

```
string variable1 = "AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD";
string variable2 = "AAA, CCC, DDD, EEE";
```

And I need the result like "BBB" (the value which is present in variable2 but not in variable1.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your efforts for this

Comment: Hi, will you always have this format `AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD` or can it also be `ValueA, ValueB ValueB, ValueC ValueC`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb300779(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = variable1.Split(new char[] {','})
                .Except(variable2.Split(new char[] {','})).ToArray();
```